# How to separate code in .net core between Minor and Major releases

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm looking for different ways to extend .Net Core webb application, using external precompiled files to get code separation for major and minor releases and customizations.
i.e. I want to add another field validation in an application without recompiling the main application. So I create the new addon /fix in a separate class and compile this to xxx this  will then override the original functionality or extend it.
Any ideas how this can be done ?

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a good idea for modifying the asp.net core application. The web deploy has the same feature will just upload the modified dll to the application.  The asp.net core just support modify the razor at runtime, but also we don't suggest use it at production environment.  If you want to use this feature, I think PHP is better.

Comment: I might have been a bit confusing, I have updated the question.

Comment: You explained what you want to do, you haven't explained why you want to do it. Is your goal Zero Downtime deployments? If so, there are better ways of accomplishing that.

Comment: [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/)?